# Squashing multiple git commits in history

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I have a repository with around 3000 commits where i want to squash around 250 of them in the middle of history between two dates like this:

`a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h--i--j--k--l--m--n`

`a--b--c--d'-------------------k--l--m--n`

I already know the dates and shas of d and j.
What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try a different approach which is kind of similar to the merge approach.

**Note:** Assuming `n` to be the latest and `a` be the oldest commit.

Create a new branch with commit `k` as head.

```
git checkout -b new-branch <commit hash of k>
```

Then, soft reset the head to the parent of commit `d`.

```
git reset --soft <commit hash of parent of d>
```

Commit the changes, as all the changes from commit `d` to `k` are not present in the staging area. (`git status` to verify)

```
git commit
```

Merge the commits post `k`,

```
git cherry-pick l^...n # Use SHA's of l and n
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is the oldest, `n` is the latest commit:

#### `git rebase` method:

```
    git rebase <sha_of_d> -i
    # replace *pick* with *squash* for commits e..j
    # save and quit
```

#### `git merge` method:

```
    git reset --hard <sha_of_d>
    git merge --squash <sha_of_k>
    git commit
    git cherry-pick <sha_of_l>^..<sha_of_n>
```

Please note:

- `git reset --hard` will throw away all your uncommitted changes.
- `git cherry-pick` ranges are supported starting from `git` v1.7.2.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but can't find a better method.

Comment: Also, if you use `vim`, use this: `:%s/pick/squash/g` to replace all `pick`'s to `squash`'es.

Comment: Thank you. That works, but prompts me to enter squash for like 250 commits. Can i pass a range of commits, for which a squash has to be done while the other commits get picked?

Comment: Unfortunately no, `git rebase` works on commits starting from `HEAD`.

Comment: Another option would be to use `git merge --squash`, but that is more painful, IMO.

Comment: The git merge method is just what i was looking for. But i have to git reset the sha of c because d is already part of what i want to squash. Also i use git merge on the sha of j, because k should not be part of it. But in general this is the perfect solution for my needs. Thank you very much